# How to Convert string XML to dataframe with only selected tags and its value in python

Tags: python, xml, pandas, dataframe

Sample of my large XML string looks like:

```
<RecordContainer RecordNumber = "1">
<catalog>
   <Person id="bk101">
      <person>
         <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
         <personal_info>
            <age>40</age>
            <DOB>19-02-1988</DOB>
         </personal_info> 
      </person>
      <books>
          <book id>1</book id>
          <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
          <price>44.95</price>
          <publish>
             <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
             <info>this is the guide to XML</info>
          </publish>
      </books>
      <books>
          <book id>2</book id>
          <title>Python for beginners</title>
          <price>21.50</price>
          <publish>
             <publish_date>2002-005-5</publish_date>
             <info>this is the guide to Python</info>
          </publish>
      </books>
 </catalog>
</RecordContainer>
<RecordContainer RecordNumber = "2">
 <catalog>  
   <Person id="bk102">
      <person>
        <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
        <personal_info>
            <age>29</age>
            <DOB>11-05-1994</DOB>
         </personal_info> 
      </person>
      <books>
          <book id>1</book id>
          <title>Scala Prgramming</title>
          <price>15.90</price>
          <publish>
             <publish_date>2011-04-10</publish_date>
             <info>this is the guide to Scala Programming</info>
          </publish>
      </books>
      <books>
          <book id>2</book id>
          <title>PySpark for beginners</title>
          <price>25.50</price>
          <publish>
             <publish_date>2012-07-21</publish_date>
             <info>PySpark Guide</info>
          </publish>
      </books>
 </catalog>
</RecordContainer>
```

My expected output is a pandas dataframe with selected tags and it's values like below:

```
Record_Number  PersonID  author   DOB   book_id1  title1   publish_date1  book_id2  title2  publish_date2
```

I have tried with **.find(.//element)** but not able to access each element individually. For parsing the file I have used the following code:

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.fromstring("<root>"+input_data+"</root>")
```

After above code tried to get each element tag and text using .find() but it is showing none as the text output.

Comment: "After above code tried..." Please don't tell us what your code does, instead *show us the actual code*.

Comment: is this xml output is a string or a xml fie?

Comment: it's a string. That is the reason i am including <root> tag for parsing.

Comment: Just adding `<root>` is not enough. The "XML" in the question is still not well-formed.

Comment: I have solved the problem. Will soon update my approach. Appreciate to get some optimised solution

Comment: @JahnabKumarDeka - Are you still planning on updating your solution?  I believe I could benefit from it.

Comment: @alofgran Yes. I will update the solution today